# Google Maps Tutorial Issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been working on trying to set up a simple google maps application for a while now, but I'm getting an issue that I can't resolve. I'll walk you through exactly what I've done so far:

- Made a new project
- Imported the google-play-services-lib as a separate project
- I went to the android properties of my project and added the google-play-services-lib as a library
- I went to android tools and added the android support libraries to my project

I added the following code to my main activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    }
}
```

I added the following code to my ma-_activity xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I added the following code to my android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.please"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <permission   android:name="com.example.please.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"                             android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.please.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.please.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY ACTUAL KEY IS HERE" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

It won't let me upload a file of my log because I'm new here, but here is a summary

```
fatal exception Main
java.lang.RuntimeException  unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MapActivity}android.view.InflateException, BinaryXML file line #7 Error inflating class fragment
```

I've tried pretty much every possible way of importing the google jar file using a different project each time and I can't get any of them to work. Does anyone have any suggestions or see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your map_activity.xml

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

into this

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```